# Keep two Twitter accounts in two separate browser tabs?

Tags: twitter, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome. Is it somehow possible to keep two different Twitter accounts in two distinct tabs within the same window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question has been asked on stackoverflow - [Multiple login in one browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24243108/4248931)

From [most upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24461607/4248931) answer of same question:

> For Chrome, there is an extension called [MultiLogin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/ijfgglilaeakmoilplpcjcgjaoleopfi?hl=en), which gives support for different sessions in each tab. Note that it is only free for personal use, so if you are using it at work, you may have to email the developer to inquire about a commercial license.

Comment: Thanks! However, this is not working entirely reliable. After period of inactivity, the second session tab is getting restored to the first one.